# Power BI execute stored procedure with user parameter on button click event

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

My requirement is I want to execute the SQL stored procedure on button click event with parameter using Power Bi reports without PowerApps & web development.

So that I can update/Insert some values in database and load the updated data from the same database.

Requesting you to please suggest method for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed explanation of using parameterized SQL Server stored proc [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/execute-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-user-parameter-in-power-bi/).

You have to manage the logic of updating/inserting data in the proc you are calling.
If you follow the method above, you can simply click refresh to fire the proc every time, without requiring web development for a custom button.

I hope this helps. :)